# How do console windows stay put even without a Console.ReadXXX() call in Channel 9 demos?

Tags: c#, console-application

In all the demos that Anders or anyone else on Channel 9 does, they have console apps which they run during the demos and those windows stay visible even after the whole of the `Main` method runs even though they never have a `Console.ReadXXX` call at the end of their program.

How does that work? I am sure I am being lazy in exploring some Visual Studio configuration option. Do you know what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "Start Without Debugging"  (Ctrl-F5), you will automatically get a pause at the end of the application, with a "Press any key to continue . . ." message.

Of course, you will have no debugger attached, so you will not hit any breakpoints.

[image]

[image]